# WPF image set boundaries

Tags: c#, wpf

How do you display a rectangle of pixels on an image file in WPF? I want to 'crop in' on the region bounded by (8,8) and (15,15), and then display that region in a WPF Image control. Creating a BitmapImage and setting the SourceRect doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be [`CroppedBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.Imaging.CroppedBitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<!-- from msdn -->
<!-- Chain a cropped bitmap off a previosly defined cropped image -->
<Image Width="200" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5">
   <Image.Source>
      <CroppedBitmap Source="{StaticResource croppedImage}" 
         SourceRect="30 0 75 50"/>
   </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: Thanks! Although I meant in the c# code, this was just what I needed!

Comment: Glad to hear it, if you want it from C#, it is still the same concept.  Create a new `CroppedBitmap` and set the original as it's `Source`.